# my wordnet lemmatizer is not lemmatizing words correctly

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

this code is running but it is not giving expected results after lemmatization. Most of the words are same after lemmatization. Can anyone highlight my mistake or suggest me some other lemmatizer for english.
Input is a column of a table e.g few rows are Alphabets, reveals, ,Bestowed , going Output: Alphabet, reveal, bestow, go.

```
    import pymysql
    from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
    conn=pymysql.connect("localhost","root","root","qwn1")
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    sql="select lemma from quranic_words where new_word=1 "
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results=cursor
    while results:
        results=cursor.fetchone()
        lemmatizer=WordNetLemmatizer()
        print( "results", repr(results))
        for w in results:
            print (lemmatizer.lemmatize(w))
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add your input and expected output to your question so that other readers can understand your problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.